# IIS URL Rewrite - any url request to redirect to a specific page without recursive rewrites

Tags: php, url, iis, url-rewriting

```
<rule name="holdingPage" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^http://www.cruiseamour.co.uk/holding.php" negate="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.cruiseamour.co.uk/holding.php" appendQueryString="false" />
    <conditions></conditions>
</rule>
```

Whilst doing some maintenance on the DB I simply want any request for a page (other than the holding page) to redirect to the holding page. At the moment the rule is redirecting requests for the holding page to the holding page causing a recursive loop but I can't figure out why.

Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `action` within the rule stull says it should redirect back to itself, setting off the recursive behavior you're describing. Try changing the `action` to this:

```
<action type="None" />
```

This should specify that no action is needed and allow the page to process/perform normally.

Comment: Thanks Liam, I need the action to apply but ONLY to URLs other than the holding page URL. Changing the action to none doesn't redirect anything.

Comment: You could have this rule in place above the global redirect, which would catch and stop the redirecting from happening. Or, you could play with the RegEx to exclude the page. I'm not in front of a server to test, but may look something like this:  

    ^http://www.cruiseamour.co.uk/(?!holding\.php$).*?\.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the "url" it compares against starts after the slash after the host name. So in your case, try: `<match url="^holding.php" negate="true"/>`